# Getting Error Forbidden, you don't have permission to access this resource, when hosting my website with apache2 on port 443

Tags: django, ubuntu, ssl, https, apache2

my django website hosted on AWS EC2 apache ubuntu has ssl certificate obtained and setup through certbot but it is not opening on port 443(HTTPS).It is showing error Forbidden 403.

There might be some permission issues. I have executed `sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/webroot/directory`, `sudo chown -R user:group /path/to/webroot/directory` commands.

apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    #Order deny,allow
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
#<Directory /srv/>
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #AllowOverride None
    #Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

000-default.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    
    #ServerName logyanlo.com
    #ServerAlias www.logyanlo.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/blog/gyanlo
    
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    
    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/blog/gyanlo/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/blog/gyanlo/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/blog/gyanlo/gyanlo>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess gyanlo python-path=/home/ubuntu/blog/gyanlo/ python-home=/home/ubuntu/blog/gyanlo_env
    WSGIProcessGroup gyanlo
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/blog/gyanlo/gyanlo/wsgi.py

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.logyanlo.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a virtual host configuration for port 443. The one you have in the question is for non-HTTPS traffic.

Comment: i have changed the configuration by commenting WSGI commands on port 80.Now it is running well on https when i give my full domain starting with www. but when i tried to run it on my domain name only without www, it is showing the same error on port 80 that i have encountered for port 443. what should i do now

Comment: You will need to use `ServerAlias` to specify other domains that Apache should listen for. An effective way to do this would be with a wildcard: `ServerAlias logyanlo.com *.logyanlo.com`

Comment: i have used server alias in the code above. i have removed comment from it. but still it's not working. should i change it to the form you have provided?

Comment: how to fix putty fatal error. i am not able to open the console